# How to get data value of a div that has no ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is part of some code on an html page that lists shopping cart products. Using JavaScript/jQuery, I need to be able to loop through the `li` items and get the div "data-" values for each. The issue that I am having is that there are no IDs for the div that has the data- value (). I only see the div for "CategoryContent".

```
    <div class="Block CategoryContent Moveable Panel" id="CategoryContent">
      <ul class="ProductList ">
        <li class="Odd">
          <div class="ProductImage QuickView" data-product="577">
             <a href="http://example.com/sweater-vest-v-neck-cotton/"><img src="http://cdn3.example.com/products/577/images/1731/2311-.jpg?c=2" alt="Sweater Vest V-Neck Cotton" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="ProductDetails">
             <a href="http://example.com/sweater-vest-v-neck-cotton/" class=" pname">Sweater Vest V-Neck Cotton</a>
          </div>
          <em class="p-price">$45.04</em>
          <div class="ProductPriceRating">
            <span class="Rating Rating0">
              <img src="http://cdn3.example.com/templates/custom/images/IcoRating0.png?t=" alt="" style="" />
            </span>
          </div>

          <div class="ProductActionAdd" style="display:;">
             <a href="http://example.com/sweater-vest-v-neck-cotton/" class="btn icon-Choose Options" title="Choose Options">Choose Options</a>
          </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
    </form>
    </div>
```

So, there is only one `li` item here, on a typical page, there are up to 9. My goal is to use JavaScript to get the `data-product` values and then use that to look up a better image thumbnail and have it replaced. So, how do I get the value set for `data-product`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy:

```
// Loop through all list items of ul.ProductList:
$("ul.ProductList li").each(function (index, element) {

    // Find the element with attribute data-product:
    $dp = $(element).find("[data-product]");

    // Get the value of attribute data-product:
    var product = $dp.attr("data-product");

    // Now set the high quality thumbnail url:
    var url = "/images/hq/" + product + ".png"; // Note that this is just an example

    // Here you can use $(element) to access to current li (and the img):
    $(element).find('.ProductImage img').attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: Why not `$('ul.ProductList li [data-product]').each(...`

Comment: Because you wouldn't have a reference to `ul.ProductList li` (var element).

Comment: you can get, `$(this).closest('li');` like you get for child using `find`

Comment: True, but why is that better? This seems more clear to me.

Comment: By using that, you're filtering only the necessary elements, in case if some `li` does not contain `data-product` attribute

Comment: Why would a `li` not contain a `data-product` attribute? I understand your confusion, but I guess that he/she means by 'that there are no IDs for the div that has the data- value', that he/she has no literal `id` attribute to access the element in JavaScript. Which he now has using `$(element)`.

Comment: @Tim  You mention that there is access to $(element) to access the current li within the loop you posted. How at this point could you access the image source to replace the src with a new value? Would you use `getElementsByClassName("img")` or some other way? Your solution looks like it might save me another loop later to update the images.

Comment: @user4708809 Indeed it safes another loop. You can access the `<img>` in the current `<li>` by using `$(element).find('.ProductImage img')`. I'll update this answer using this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$("#CategoryContent div[data-product]").each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('data-product'));
});
```

Comment: `$(this).data('product')` can also be used instead of `attr`

Comment: Please add some explanation, only code dump are not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#CategoryContent div[data-product]');
var index = 0, length = divs.length, prodIds = [];
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    prodIds.push(divs[index].getAttribute('data-product'));
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/we5q7omg/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class name to get the data-product

```
var products = document.getElementsByClassName("ProductImage");
for(var i=0; i<products.length;i++)
{
   console.log(products[i].getAttribute("data-product"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can get the elements with the `data-product` attribute by simply calling

```
$('[data-product]')

// Or if you only want the data-product elements within the UL.
$('ul').find('[data-product]')
```

From there you can simply do pull the products from the elements. For Example:

```
var products = $('[data-product]').map(function() { 
  return $(this).data('product'); 
});
```